# Laravel 5.4 sortBy() not working when returned as JSON

Tags: php, laravel

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby)

My laravel Version 
const VERSION = '5.4.15';

HomeController

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');

$sorted->values()->all();

return $sorted;
```

Result when returned as JSON:

```
{
     0: {
          name: "Desk",
          price: 200
     },
     1: {
          name: "Chair",
          price: 100
     },
     2: {
          name: "Bookcase",
          price: 150
     }
 }
```

What did I miss? Why isn't `sortBy` working?

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but your example differs from the docs in that you `return $sorted` rather than `return $sorted->values()->all();`  If the sort is applied at the time `all()` is called, it may produce a different result. According to the docs, the original keys are kept and so if returned as json, they may end up sorted back into numeric order.

Comment: Can't really reproduce this. Is this the raw output or are you running it through any sort of JSON prettyfier?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - While the OP _should_ return `$sorted->values()->all()` if they want an array with indexed keys, simply returning `$sorted` should still return a sorted collection. The sort is _not_ done lazily.

Comment: Deleted my answer as like @apokryfos, I'm unable to reproduce. And as @JosephSilber mentioned, simply returning `$sorted` _does_ return the desired results. Thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: By the way I'm using https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter in chrome which does produce the same output as you're showing here but that's due to a "feature" of the browser plugin, raw view looks fine.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks you solved my problem

Comment: @GoranSiriev I didn't. There was no problem

Comment: @GoranSiriev Could you tell me what the solution was? I have been with this same problem for hours and without solving it

Comment: @FeRcHo 
Remove plugin from chrome plugin json-formatter or use firefox